# Display array with array_search

Tags: php, arrays, file, csv

I have an array of csv elements and I want to retrieve the key of the column 'Due Date' (the result is 10) and display the array at the column 10. However, it doesn't display the result but it will show the column 1 and I don't know why.

Code:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
//$line is an array of the csv elements
    $value = array_search('Due Date', $line); 
    print_r($line[$value]);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to first have a look $line array, to see how data comes and does really "Due Date" exists in $line. then try array_search

Comment: It exists I test it

Comment: Then see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39269477/1960558

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this so you can easily get the column number 10:

```
$var = array();
while($row = fgetcsv($yourFile)) {
   $var[] = $row;
}

//Get Column 10
$var[] = $row[9];
```

**Edit:**

```
<?php
$valueOfSearch = "YOUR VALUE OF SEARCH";
$linesOfCsv = file('YOUR PATH.csv');
$lineNumberOfCSV = false;

while (list($key, $line) = each($linesOfCsv) and !$lineNumberOfCSV) {
  $lineNumberOfCSV = (strpos($line, $valueOfSearch) !== FALSE);
}

if($lineNumberOfCSV){
  //Add YOUR CONDITION
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to search the column by value and adapt the code if the column value is different of 'Due Date'

Comment: you want to find a column of due date or find a value in due date ? please clarify your answer.

Comment: find a column withe the value 'Due date'

Comment: Check my edit version. Add your column in condition.

Answer (score 0):

Open the fine and take csv values inside an array and close the file. After that try your logic.

So to get value you can use:

```
$file = 'file.csv';
$line = array();
$file = fopen($file,"r");

while(! feof($file))
{
 $line = fgetcsv($file);
}

fclose($file);

$key = array_search('Due Date', $line);

print_r($line[$key]);
```

Comment: I have a warning Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array and no response

Comment: Then I sure, something wrong with your csv file. because I already tested my code and it works. Can you share your csv file?

Comment: Swimlane,Column,ID,Title,Card type,Card color,Priority,Assigned to,Description,External Link,Due Date,Tags,Next Date,Lead Marketing,Lead Technical,Lead Project,Business status,Partner mgmt status,API Exposition status,OPE product status,OPE infra status,Service mgmt status,Progress [%],Created at,Archived at 
Externe,opportunities,685,API Orange Wholesale FR,API lead,orange,0,"","","","","","",B. Mignot,P. Metton,not assigned,"","","","","","","","December 03, 2014 18:28",""

Comment: Your csv file is correct and I am getting data as well. So something wrong with your file path. I updated code and make sure your csv file and php file are in same directory or path is correct. So to check path is correct or not you can use print_r($line);

Comment: My result with print_r($line[$key]) : Due DateExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterneExterne. So the column Swimlane and not Due Date

Comment: I am sure, something you did not follow because I am getting right answer.

Comment: Gist just in case you need: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/avastamin/04dc8d244ef4367db11261f9b0832d5a/raw/bb1033fb565a3e71b4dab1661a581bf042c747ca/index.php

Comment: I have a warning Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array

Comment: @Bourg Warning is clear that, something wrong with your file path or permission. What do you see if you use: print_r($line)?

Comment: Nothing just the warning

Comment: What is your answer ??

Comment: it's an array with all data from csv file. Then recheck your code and file permission. Probably your csv file is not readable.